# Can I deserialize a list of heterogenous XML elements into records and sealed types with Jackson XmlMapper?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

Let's say I have a XML structure where one level contains mixed elements, like this:

```xml
<bowl>
    <banana />
    <apple />
    <banana />
</bowl>
```

Using `XmlMapper`, is there any way of deserialize this to a structure like this?

```java
sealed interface Fruit {
    record Banana() implements Fruit {}
    record Apple() implements Fruit {}
}

record Bowl(
    List<Fruit> fruits
) {
```

I have been trying the annotations (`@JsonTypeInfo`, `@JsonSubTypes`) that I usually use for these situations when decoding JSON, but can't find a combination that works.

Do I have to use a custom deserializer like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792527/deserializing-xml-list-with-jackson), or is there a way to do this using `@JsonSubTypes`?